# Disk IOs spikes at set times in CentOS

Tags: centos, munin, io, graph

I recently installed Munin on my servers. Now 2 of my machines show big spikes in DiskIO at the same time, everyday at 4am.

I run Centos 5.6 (64bit). I've checked my cron logs, and I have no personal scripts running around those times. Also, my hoster does not take backups, as I run my own backups, but they run at 1AM, not 4AM.

My Question is: Does CentOS run any scheduled processes that can take up this much DiskIO?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, 0402 is when a ton of system-maintenance cron jobs kick off; it's normal. expected, and harmless.  In `/etc/crontab` you should find the entry that says

```
02 4 * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.daily
```

If you want to change the kickoff time, alter those first two figures accordingly.  If you want to see what they're doing, perhaps with a view to seeing what all that IO activity is, look in `/etc/cron.daily`.  **Don't** stop them from running!